# Open a pop up window maximumize to the user's screen configuration

Tags: asp.net, popup

What is best way to open a pop up window maximized to the user's screen configuration?  I am using C# ASP.NET 3.5 web site project.

**Update:**

@Anthony - The windows xp task bar covers up some of the browser window.  How do I set to maxmmumize and stop at the windows xp task bar?

**Update 1:**

I used the following the solution to maxumize the pop up window, but it opens the window first then moves it to the upper left corner of the screen.  Is there a way just to open the pop up at the 0,0 position?

```
function openMaxWindow(url) {
    var name = "MyWindow";
    var features = "status=1,toolbar=1,location=1,menubar=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,top=0,left=0,height=" + screen.availHeight + ",width=" + screen.availWidth;

    var newWindow = window.open(url, name, features); 
}
```

**Update 2:**

Figured it out, I needed to add top=0 and left=0 to the features list.

Comment: If this isn't an internal app, PLEASE DON'T DO THIS! I have my browser set just to the size I like, and any site that messes with my preferences will never see me again.

Comment: @Mark - This is an intranet application.

Comment: @Michael, thanks for that. I hope the same is true of whoever else finds this question, through Google or whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use javascript to run

`var newWindow = window.open(); newWindow.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);`

Obviously, you need to use the appropriate parameters to the `window.open()` statement.

[This link also shows how to do it](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/maximize.html)

**Edit**

```
newWindow.moveTo(0,0);
newWindow.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
```

Comment: I don't know your specific requirements, but keep in mind moveTo() and resizeTo() won't work in some browsers. For example, in Firefox if you go to Tools > Options... > Content > JavaScript > Advanced... and uncheck Move or resize existing windows the code presented will fail. Even with that option enabled, the code presented will (in a default Firefox configuration) open a new tab, then resize the existing browser to fill the available screen space, something your users may find annoying.

Comment: @Grant - This is an intranet application and our default compamny browser is IE7.

Answer (score 1):

```
function maximizeWindow() {
  window.moveTo(0, 0);
  if (document.all) {
    top.window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight);
  } else if (document.layers||document.getElementById) {
    if (top.window.innerHeight < screen.availHeight || top.window.innerWidth < screen.availWidth) {
      top.window.outerHeight = screen.availHeight;
      top.window.outerWidth = screen.availWidth;
    }
  }
}
```